# dconf change a string key

Tags: bash, scripts, dconf

I'm trying to change a string based dconf key with a bash script, using the following command line:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/show-directory-item-counts 'never'
```

But it return the following error:

```
error: 0-5:unknown keyword

Usage:
  dconf write KEY VALUE 

Write a new value to a key

Arguments:
  KEY         A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
  VALUE       The value to write (in GVariant format)
```

Can someone help me?

edit 1 : I'm trying to make nautilus to not count the number of item in the directory (for optimization purpose)

Comment: What are you trying to do? What tutorial are you following?

Comment: I'm trying to make nautilus stop counting the number of item in each directory.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The value needs additional quoting i.e. to assign GVariant string value `'foo'` you need to write the value argument as `"'foo'"`

```
dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/show-directory-item-counts "'never'"
```

See [dconf — Simple tool for manipulating a dconf database](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-tool.html) at https://developer.gnome.org/

Answer (score 10):

What steeldriver said is the right way to do it. However using [gsettings](https://developer.gnome.org/GSettings/) is an easier way to archive the same.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-directory-item-counts never
```

Comment: Using gsettings is probably the better approach.  See https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-tool.html, where it states: "dconf cannot perform type and consistency checks on values. The gsettings utility is an alternative if such checks are needed."

Comment: Seems gsettings has not the same keys as dconf, example `dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/scale/initiate-edge` returns `'TopRight'`, but `gsettings get org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.scale initiate-edge` returns `No such schema 'org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.scale'`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

STATE=`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons`
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true|false
```

Comment: How come you are piping the results of `gsettings` into the command `false`? :-P