# gsettings - change privacy settings via command line

Tags: command-line, dconf, privacy, gsettings

I know how to change privacy settings via GUI (System Settings > Security & Privacy), but I'd like to be able to do it from command line.

#### What I did to find out

I ran the command:

```
dconf watch /
```

to see what changes were made. About the command (from `man dconf`):

```
watch
    Watch a key or directory for changes.
```

Subsequently, I changed settings via GUI to see what happened in the output of the command. It showed:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/privacy/remember-recent-files false
/com/canonical/unity/lenses/remote-content-search 'none'
/org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
/org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled false
```

My question is: how can I use this information to change the settings from command line?

Comment: So your goal is to alter those `dconf ` schemas  you got in the output of `dconf watch /` ?

Comment: my goal is to learn how to change the GUI settings in command line.

Comment: that's a broad topic . There's a lot of things that change the settings, not just one tool .  Since that's such a broad topic,  you probably won't receive an answer on that.  However those specific settings that you've listed can be changed with `dconf write KEY VALUE` .  see http://askubuntu.com/q/22313/295286 and http://askubuntu.com/q/487206/295286 for some info .

Comment: Hi blowfishhgpg, could you mention if the answer is what you are looking for, and if you manage?

Comment: Great! But I can't manage to disable the diagnostics  sent to Canonical. Are these keys not in dconf? At least watch doen't show anything

Answer (score 11):

#### Different ways to edit those settings

The settings you mention are stored in the `dconf` database in `~/.config/dconf` (in binary format). This database can either be directly edited with `dconf`, or via `gsettings`. The difference is explained at the last section of this answer.

Once you have the information, posted in your question, you can therefore change the corresponding settings in two different ways. 
Using your first example (setting `remember-recent-files`):

*using dconf write:*

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/privacy/remember-recent-files false
```

or

*using gsettings set:*

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-recent-files false
```

Similarly, ***reading*** the current setting:

*using dconf read:*

```
dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/privacy/remember-recent-files
```

or

*using gsettings get:*

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-recent-files
```

In the first case, you edit the `dconf` database directly, in the latter you are using `gsettings`, which is a CLI frontend to dconf.

#### Which way to prefer; dconf or gsettings?

To protect the integrity of your `dconf` database, in general, it is considered better practice to use `gsettings`.

Frome [this link](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-tool.html), we read:

> The dconf program can perform various operations on a dconf database,
>   such as reading or writing individual values or entire directories.
>   This tool operates on dconf directly, without using gsettings schema
>   information. Therefore, it cannot perform type and consistency checks
>   on values. The gsettings(1) utility is an alternative if such checks
>   are needed.  You can see `gsettings` as the cli-frontside to `dconf`.

Read more on [gsettings](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html) and [dconf](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-tool.html).

Comment: They don't seem to be alternatives: I wonder why I can't access to /apps/... with `gsettings`