# set dconf-editor values programatically

Tags: unity, gnome, bash, shortcut-keys, compiz

Is there a way that I can access and edit dconf-editor values programatically, I mean using phython or bash?

I want to develop a simple tool to edit some window management shortcuts. I know there are tools like compiz which provides this already, but need to have something quick and simple to work best with my requirements.

I there some sort of a API for dconf-editor? or an API for window management keyboard short cuts in general.

Basically I want to edit Switch Windows shortcuts (Alt + Tab) from bash or some other scripting language, i.e, without using a GUI.

Please advice.

Comment: I don't know about APIs but did you look at *gsettings*? For the window manager, you may need to be specific about what you intend doing.

Comment: I want to set switch window short cuts using bash or python, i know those can be edited from compiz, dconf-editor, etc. I want to do it from bash or some programming language

Comment: `from gi.repository import Gio`  :)

Comment: As well as `gsettings`, there is a `dconf` command-line tool that you can use directly from the shell - see [What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Repeat question https://askubuntu.com/questions/755020/gsettings-change-privacy-settings-via-command-line

Answer (score 1):

For Python, use `Gio` module. Specifically, here's an example of two functions I use in my own code (feel free to see how they're used within my [Launcher List Indicator](https://github.com/SergKolo/launcher-list-indicator/blob/master/launcher-list-indicator)):

```
from gi.repository import Gio

# Define your own class here 

    # Note that these use `self` for use with classes
    # this could be removed otherwise

def gsettings_get(self, schema, path, key):
    """Get value of gsettings schema"""
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema, path)
    return gsettings.get_value(key)

def gsettings_set(self, schema, path, key, value):
    """Set value of gsettings schema"""
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema, path)
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return gsettings.set_strv(key, value)
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return gsettings.set_int(key, value)
```

These functions make getting and setting values easy and similar to the command-line utilities; `schema`, `path`, and `key` values are all strings. For instance, to set Unity launcher position to "Bottom" you would do:

```
self.gsettings_set( 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher', 'launcher-position', 'Bottom')
```

For shell scripts, there are `dconf` and `gsettings` command-line tools, the later being a front-end to `dconf`. The `gsettings` command is preferred because it performs safety checks on the input values.  Example of usage:

```
 gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position 'Bottom'
```

You can call these two from python using `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.check_output()`, but this has the overhead of spawning extra process, which is unnecessary (And if  you're going to do it Pythonic way, do it right via the API).

See also

- [Do GUI based application execute shell commands in the background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849304/do-gui-based-application-execute-shell-commands-in-the-background/849312#849312)