# Where do I find the “privacy settings” in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, system-settings, privacy

When a Firefox extension tries to make use of [native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging), my system opens a popup that reads:

> **Allow Firefox Web Browser to start WebExtension backend?**
>
> Firefox Web Browser is requesting to launch "[native application description]" ([native application name]).
>
> This permission can be changed at any time from the privacy settings.
>
> OK Cancel

Where do I find the referenced privacy settings? [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/755020) mentions “System Settings > Security & Privacy,” but I don’t have that – is it a GNOME thing? (Even if it is, I still need to be able to revoke the permission somewhere.) I’m using Kubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Since Firefox issued the message,  it's talking about firefox's "Privacy settings".

Comment: Or probably about the settings of the extension itself.

Comment: @mook765 I wrote the extension and it has no such settings.

Comment: @waltinator I don’t think Firefox would call itself “Firefox Web Browser” (rather than just “Firefox”) – it seems more like the system inserted the full name of the application there. I also haven’t found anything in Firefox’s settings. – And the popup uses the KDE icon and its title bar reads: “Allow Firefox Web Browser to start WebExtension backend? — **Portal**” (Where would I upload the screenshot?)