# Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME 3.36 - Remove terminal window titlebar buttons

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, 20.04, titlebar, csd

Is there a way to remove the new tab, search and what seems like a settings button from the window title bar in GNOME 3.36 Terminal.

What I want is to change the title bar from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

I would like to remove these buttons since I never use them, and having them there seems like a waste of vertical real estate. If I want to search for something in the terminal window I usually do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. When adding a new tab I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and I usually never change any of the settings after my initial setup.

Comment: It might be just me, but I don't see how exactly you are going to save "*vertical real estate*" just by disabling those buttons.

Comment: I am assuming that if I remove those buttons, the height of the title bar should shrink to fit only the title and the maximize, minimize and close buttons. I know it might not free up a whole lot of pixels but seeing those buttons there is extremely annoying and serves no purpose when you use keyboard shortcuts a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the CSD (client side decoration) a.k.a. the headerbar, and thus revert to the SSD (server side decoration), the traditional behavior.

In order to do so, open `dconf-editor`, navigate to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy` and set `headerbar` to `false`. Then restart gnome-terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but is there a way to do this from the terminal as I would like to put it in my setup scripts. I had to first disable `Use default value` and then I could set the custom value to `False` and restart the gnome shell after closing all terminal windows.

Comment: @Sajeeb the command `gsettings set org.gnome.terminal.legacy headerbar false` should work.

Comment: unfortunately that gives me: `No such schema “org.gnome.terminal.legacy”`. I did however try `gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar false`, but that doesn't seem to work as when I go to dconf and navigate to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/headerbar` I can still see `Use default value` enabled with default value being `Nothing`.

Comment: @Sajeeb Try the [`dconf write` command](https://askubuntu.com/a/487216/480481) then.

Comment: @Sajeeb +1 for "closing ALL terminal windows", that's crucial. Btw.: ```dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/settings/headerbar false``` works.